# Using R or Python plot worldmap with countries from simple list colored

Tags: python, r, plot, rworldmap

I have the list of countries :

```
("Albania", "Algeria", "Anguilla", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Congo", "Congo (DRC)", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Curacao", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji Islands", "Finland", "France", "French Guiana", "Gabon", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong SAR", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Ireland", "Isle of Man", "Israel", "Italy", "Ivory Coast / Côte d'Ivoire", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macao SAR", "Macedonia, Former Yugoslav Republic of", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Mali", "Malta", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Norway", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Réunion", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadine", "Samoa", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "South Korea", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "St. Maarten", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Taiwan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "Uruguay", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands, British", "Virgin Islands, U.S.", "Zambia"))
```

And when I try to plot it by R:

```
map('worldHires', 
c("Albania", "Algeria", "Anguilla", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Congo", "Congo (DRC)", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Curacao", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji Islands", "Finland", "France", "French Guiana", "Gabon", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong SAR", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Ireland", "Isle of Man", "Israel", "Italy", "Ivory Coast / Côte d'Ivoire", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macao SAR", "Macedonia, Former Yugoslav Republic of", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Mali", "Malta", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Norway", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Réunion", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadine", "Samoa", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "South Korea", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "St. Maarten", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Taiwan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "Uruguay", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands, British", "Virgin Islands, U.S.", "Zambia"))
```

I get:
[image: Incorrect world map]
What I am doing wrong or maybe there is much easier way to plot worldmap?
And how to plot all other uncolored or colored in another color?

Answer (score 2):

This line might work:

```
map("world", fill=TRUE, col="white", bg="lightblue", ylim=c(-60, 90), mar=c(0,0,0,0))
```

Also this is a good website to look at: https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-beginners-plotting-locations-on-to-a-world-map/

Comment: Ok, this code draws the correct map, but how to fill list of countries with green color? For example I have list `c <- c("Albania", "Algeria", "Anguilla", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina")`

Comment: Try changing `col="white"` to `col="green"`.

Comment: But I want to color only few countries, not all.